# mysql blob with mvc and nhibernate

Tags: mysql, nhibernate

I am trying to pull a blob from a mysql table and display it on an mvc view page.  When I try to access it, it is just coming up as System.byte[].  I tried adding tostring(), but get the same results.
I also tried BitConverter.ToString, but then I get what appears to be a hex string (43-6F-6E-66.....).

How do I get plain text from that?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by using Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myBlobField)

Thanks

Comment: You wouldn't have needed that if you had mapped it as a string property / StringClob type

Comment: Do you mean by just adding type="StringClob" to my mapping xml file?